# unable to post a https WebRequest in .net?

Tags: .net, proxy, networking, webrequest, client-certificates

Hi i am encountering problems trying to post a WebRequest under Https.

i received the following errors

## 1.-The underlying connection was closed: Unable to connect to the remote server.

## 2.-the operation TimeOut

## 3-The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS.

i tried with about 3 or 4 different proxies of my company and the customer company and not even when i am directly with the ISP provider with no restrictions, i get the above errors  when executing the following method

```
WebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

this occurs behind a proxy or not, the request can only be succesfully post from one single PC which is behind a proxy. the proxy doesn't have a client certificate installed.

this is under .net framework  1.1 and
the request already contains network credentials.

what could be?

## Update

the inner exception the 3rd error is the following: 
 The function completed successfully, but must be called again to complete the context

according to iisper.h [documentation](http://doc.ddart.net/msdn/header/include/issperr.h.html) this error belongs to  the

```
//
// MessageId: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
//
// MessageText:
//
//  The function completed successfully, but must be called
//  again to complete the context
//
#define SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED            ((HRESULT)0x00090312L)
```

on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375924(VS.85).aspx) this refers to

SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
 The client must send the output token to the server and wait for a return token. The returned token is then passed in another call to InitializeSecurityContext (Schannel). The output token can be empty.

does this means the  PC lacks a client certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole number of things that could be complicating things, as far as inconsistencies with the SSL certs, etc.  But first, you should do some basic debugging to rule out the obvious things:

-- Did you try sending a simple web request to other servers?  Try both (unsecured) http and (secured) https

-- Did you try connecting from another computer, or from another network?  You mentioned that the client is behind a proxy; try a computer w/o a proxy first, to rule that out.

-- Are you making multiple WebRequests within the session?  There is a hard-limit on the number of open requests, so make sure you're closing them after you get the WebResponse.  Perhaps make a test program with just one request.

If that doesn't narrow it down, then it's probably something more complicated, with their the server or the proxy.  You can track outgoing network packets with a program such as netshark to try to track down where things are getting stuck.

Comment: i already try different networks, do you think maybe the machine that can post to the service has a client certificate. i cant access this machine and i was told i didnt had one

Comment: this is a single request also already debugged with the same resutls

Comment: sounds like an ip restriction

Answer (score 1):

You could make a trace of the HTTP traffic using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) or a network packet sniffing tool like [<s>Ethereal</s> Whireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on the machine where it is working, and on one of the other machines, and compare the results. This is fairly low-level, but might throw some light on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

- If you can telnet from different machines to  443 then it is not the first two, as that means the client machine is receiving requests on that port.

On windows that would be

```
telnet <domainname> 443
```

and if it connects the screen will go blank (hit return a few times to exit)

- The proxies may or may not actually care about your request if it is under HTTPS as they can't read it.
- Do the other machines have the client certificate and the certificate chain installed?

Comment: how can i now if a client certificate is needed on the machine?

Comment: if you go to the url in a browser then it will prompt you for a cert if one is needed.  If one is needed then you are going to have to ask the people who run the server which one you need.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate name probably doesn't match. This is often the case with selfsigned certificates.

The solution is to write your own authentication routine where you either always return true or do the necessary authentication to make sure the certificate is valid.

```
// .NET 2.0+
...
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += MyValidationCallback
...
public bool MyValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors err)
{
  return true;
}

// .NET 1.1
public class MyCertificatePolicy : ICertificatePolicy
{
  public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
...
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyCertificatePolicy();
...
```

Comment: the post can be made from only one computer so this means the ssl certificate its correct.

Comment: I already try this but while debugging it does not stop on the CheckValidationResult so my guess is that there is problem during handshake 

Thanks

Comment: On C# 2.0+, the shortest way to express this is: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };`

Comment: You're correct. However I wanted to illustrate the difference with .NET 1.1 and 2.0+.